# How can I remove !important in other rules?

Tags: css

is it possible to do something like this:

```
.overlay {
    display: none !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .overlay {
        display: none !not-important;
    }
}
```

so I can override it by javascript code just in mobiles.
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override !important with your own !important, if it comes later in the css processing. However you can also use !important on a *more specific* element. So given the first !important is on ".overlay" if you had an id on your overlay, say "myid" then if your rule was:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #myid {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Then it would override the first, as its selector is more specific.

Comment: tnx, but still I cant use $('.overlay').show(); in javascript code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the display rule in 786px style, then you can write something like;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .overlay {
        display: inline (or block or anything else);
    }
}
```

According to my knowledge, you have to write display property for all the other screen widths separately.